# Split on only one consecutive occurrence of a character

Tags: python, regex

I wish to split the following:

```
"one_two_three__four"
```

so that it becomes:

```
["one", "two", "three", "_four"]
```

What regex would allow me to do this?

I've tried:

```
import re
re.split('_', 'one_two_three__four')
```

Comment: Use look arounds `(?<!_)_` matches `_` that is *not* preceded by `_`.

Comment: @Baz could you add some more explanation to your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x="one_two_three__four"
print re.split(r"(?<!_)_",x)
```

You can use `lookbehind` to make sure it split by first `_` when many are there.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])_
```

Using positive lookbehind you can

Comment: Beware, `\w` includes `_`.